# insert into MySQL server real time and date

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I have this MySQL query:

```
$SQLquery = "INSERT INTO `experimental`.`comments` (`comment_id`, `comment_dt`) 
             VALUES (NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
```

When I execute this line with PHP into the MySQL Database at `comment_dt` row appears **my computer local time and date**. Does anybody know how to set to appear in my database a **server local and time date?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way will be that you should make your `comment_dt` column `DATETIME` type and set default value `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. No need to manually insert it through insert query.

Using this each time your `comment_dt` will be automatically updated with server  date-time whenever a new row inserted.

```
ALTER TABLE comments ADD comment_dt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: ALTER TABLE  `comments` ADD  `comment_dt` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    
    MySQL error: 
    
    #1067 - Invalid default value for 'comment_dt' 

Why I get this error when I want to make `comment_dt` column `DATETIME` ??

Comment: use timestamp type instead of datetime type

Comment: Ok I solved this, but into my database is still entered my computer date and time. For example if I change my local computer date to year 2010 when I execute the MySQL query line with PHP in my database will be stocked a wrong date.

Comment: It can't be . where is your database server ? on localhost?

Comment: yes. it's if running from localhost it will take from local system

Answer (score 1):

```
$SQLquery = "INSERT INTO `experimental`.`comments` (`comment_id`, `comment_dt`) VALUES (NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());";
```

use MySQL Server function CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()

Comment: When I use CURDATE() function in database `comment_dt` column appears: 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: What's your comment_dt data type? and you can try running "SELECT  CURDATE()" in mysql command line tool